# Haskell how could I repeat elements in list when I reach the last one element in the list?

Tags: list, haskell

I an new to Haskell programming, and I was tending to create a function that can repeat each elements in the list in n times, the problem is when I reach the last one element from the list and I want to return to the first one in the element and do it again, Like

```
repeat :: Int -> [t] ->[t]
repeat 0 [] = []
repeat n (x:xs)
       | n > 0 = x : repeat (n-1) xs
       | n < 0 =[]
```

This only can print the list when n is exactly the same as the size of the list, and there would be error if n > length list
The possible result should be like this:

```
repeat 6 [1,2,3]
```

the desired result would be : 1,2,3,1,2,3

what should I edit if I want to get the first element in the list and print again?
Thanks!

Comment: `let repeat n = take n . cycle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark Seemann comment is as simple as taking `n` elements from the cycle of the list, so

```
repeat :: Int -> [t] -> [t]
repeat n = take n . cycle
```

If you want a fully expanded code would be more or less like this:

```
repeat :: Int -> [t] ->[t]
repeat 0 [] = []
repeat n (x:xs) | n > 0     = x : repeat (n-1) (xs ++ [x])
                | otherwise = []
```

The idea is that each item you consume you append to the list to be processed.
Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/JzdT/0)

Comment: That`s so cool, Thank you for your explanation. That`s really helpful!

Comment: What are the consequences for performance of having `xs ++ [x]` as the second argument to the recursive call the `repeate`? I think that adding to the end of the list makes the function running time quadratic in the number of elements in the list. (Since Haskell is lazy I think the way this will manifest is that to get one element from the list N thunks will have to be evaluated (where N is the number of elements))). The solution in [Chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45542340/452775) does not have this problem.

Comment: @Lii, that is totally true, I just keep it simple for explaining the main idea, they way to go is using the `repeat n = take n . cycle` approach.

Answer (score 1):

A basic alternative is to keep two lists around: one of them is "consumed" through pattern matching, while the other remembers the full list, so that we can start over when needed.

```
-- requires n >= 0 and nonempty full
repeatAux :: Int -> [t] -> [t] ->[t]
repeatAux 0 _      _full = []
repeatAux n []     full  = repeatAux n full full
repeatAux n (x:xs) full  = x : repeatAux (n-1) xs full

repeat :: Int -> [t] ->[t]
repeat n _ | n <= 0 = []
repeat _ []   = error "repeat: empty list with n>0"
repeat n full = repeatAux n full full
```

This can be improved using a local function, so that we can avoid to pass around the `full` list.

```
repeat :: Int -> [t] ->[t]
repeat n _ | n <= 0 = []
repeat _ [] = error "repeat: empty list with n>0"
repeat n full = go n full
   where
   go 0 _      = []
   go n []     = go n full
   go n (x:xs) = x : go (n-1) xs
```